# Potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

i am using mce editor in a user control and  added `ValidateRequest="false"` in page directive on which i have used that control then also I  am getting "A potentially dangerous `Request.Form` value was detected" error. How to solve this?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 you may need to change your web config too.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> in web.config.
```

When you change page like validateRequest="false" make sure you are HTML encoding strings.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the ValidateRequest="false" attribute to be applied, you must add the following entry

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

to your web.config.